# How to replicate a global variable in C#?

Tags: c#, operating-system, cosmos

I have a variable in one loop in C# that cannot be recognized in the other one, and I am aware that it is not possible to create a true global variable in C#, however I wonder if one can mimic one. Some of my code is this:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("write"))
    {
        var tempctr = line.Replace("(", "");
        var tempctr2 = line.Replace(")", "");
        var ctr = tempctr2.Remove(0, 6);
        Console.Write(ctr);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("sayinput"))
    {
        Console.Write(usrinput);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("inputget"))
    {
        var tempctr = line.Replace("(", "");
        var tempctr2 = line.Replace(")", "");
        var ctr = tempctr2.Remove(0, 9);
        Console.Write(ctr);
        string usrinput = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The code reads from a text file and runs a certain command based on what is in the text. My intention is for it to create a variable with **inputget** and spit it back out with **sayinput**.
And the first *usrinput* reference is an error, since the variable is declared outside of the loop.

Comment: Please explain some more and display more code, it is very unclear from the question what you want to achieve.

Comment: you definitly should read about variable scopes in c#, e.g. here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Comment: You don't need a global variable, you just need to declare `usrinput` in a scope where it's accessible in every place you plan to use it. I'd move the declaration before the foreach. As HimBromBeere said, you need to read up on scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a global variable here. Just declare `usrinput` outside your loop, like so:

```
string usrinput = "";

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("write"))
    {
        //...
    }
    else if (line.Contains("sayinput"))
    {
        Console.Write(usrinput);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("inputget"))
    {
        // ...
        usrinput = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is not possible to create a true global variable in C#,

Static variable on a class. Done. Global in the definition of any global variable (i.e. you must be in the same process). And standard C#.

Comment: I doubt that would help OP, as it´s really minimalstically written. In fact OP lacks the language-basics, how should he/she understand your answer?

Comment: By looking up the terms in the C# langauge reference he should study. I would write a little more if it would not be so totally basic and fundamental.